# Sentence structure "I'm [doing something] because [reason]"?

Tags: grammar, usage, sentence-structure

I am familiar with the sentence structure "因为。。。所以。。。," but what is the correct way to say "I am [doing something] because [reason]"?

For example, "I am asking this question because I am clueless."

Does "因为。。。所以。。。" still apply in this case?

Comment: Not related to your question, but it might be a good idea to not use Chinese fullstops for your ellipsis. Have a look at the [Chinese Wikipedia article for ellipsis](http://zh.wikipedia.org/zh-cn/%E7%9C%81%E7%95%A5%E5%8F%B7), which describes methods to type out the ellipsis using various IMEs

Comment: @YiJiang易江: It's difficult for me to understand, but I have a Croatian layout, with SCIM on Linux, they probably haven't covered that.. I've seen only SHIFT+6 there, for me that only gives an ampersand.

Comment: To keep the Chinese translation in the same order as the English equivalent, you could say "之所以我现在正在做.. 是因为..."

Comment: @Flake: Great, please add an it as an alternative in the answers, it's more prominent and you'll get some upvotes ;) My grammar book says 之 is optional, is that correct?

Comment: @drHannibalLecter Done that. Added few more things.

Comment: @Flake: Great! Hmmm..it appears I've reached my daily voting limit..vote to be delivered..:)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To answer the question:

English phrase

> "I am [doing something] because [reason]"

has Chines equivalent, which preserves the same sentence order, as:

> "之所以我现在正在做.. 是因为..."

Though, I am not sure if `所以我在做.. 是因为` is wrong, the `之` in this sentence is not really optional, i.e. saying `之所以我在做.. 是因为` is much more natural than `所以我在做.. 是因为`, at least to me.

But normally, I would say

> "我现在正在做.. 是因为..."

Or, to add blaming emotion into the sentence:

> "我现在正在做.. 还不是因为..."

E.g.

> "我现在正在写报告, 还不是因为你忘了提前告诉我."

=

> "I am still writing the report, because you forgot to tell me earlier!"

Comment: I'm a bit confused about the 还不是 part, how does it translate to English?

Comment: Wow, just realized this part is really not that easy to explain in English. I will post a question for this when I have the time. ;) For now, FYI, this part is oral Chinese, somewhat not that standard, but as I know, quite common and nature.

Answer (score 5):

I think “因为。。。所以。。。” still applies in this case. Or you could say “我。。。是因为。。。”

For example:

> 我吃蛋糕是因为我饿了。= *I am eating the cake because I am hungry.*
>   <sub>Wǒ chī dàn gāo shì yīn wèi wǒ è le</sub>

Comment: I added the pinyin, but I'm not 100% sure it's correct. I used the dictionary so hopefully it is... :)

Comment: Thanks for the editing Alenanno. The pinyin you added is totally correct.

Answer (score 3):

As long as there is a cause and effect logic in the sentence, "因为...所以..." applies. Therefore, the below situations all mean "因为...所以..."

A because B

B, therefore/hence/so, A

B causes/contributes to/leads to A

etc...